# LESS extend pseudoclasses as !important

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-selectors, less

I want to extend some bootstrap classes as !important. This is what I do:

```
@import (less, reference) "bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
.my-row {
    .row !important;
}
```

And this is what I get:

```
.my-row:before,
.my-row:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.my-row:after {
    clear: both;
}
.my-row {
    margin-left: -10px !important;
    margin-right: -10px !important;
}
```

Unfortunately selectors with pseudoclasses are not marked as !important. How should I extend class to make everything marked as !important?

Comment: `!important` is bad. Why don't you just increase the specificity of your selector instead?

Comment: !important is a horrible implementation of CSS, why exactly do you need to use it?

Comment: This `!important` technique is used in embeddable JavaScript widgets

Answer (score 0):

first of all as James and Kyle said. use of `!important` is horrible but in some case we need to use it, I can understand.

in you case. you can use `!important` to row class but not on `pseudo-classes` there is limitation.

but still you can use following solution. if you only need it for `.row`. it will work as you want.

```
    .my-row {
      .row !important;
      &:before,
      &:after {
          content: " " !important;;
          display: table !important;;
      }
      &:after {
          clear: both !important;;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any more generic solution? I need to import plenty of rules

Comment: then DO NOT use !important for everything. try to find another solution.